# new column created in dataframe based on conditions in other columns - but data being read incorrectly

Tags: r

I have a dataframe describing observations of bird species in various locations based on month and year. It looks like this:

```
       COMMON.NAME OBSERVATION.COUNT                 LOCALITY Month Year
            Bushtit                 1                Vancouver   Jan 2000
   Lapland Longspur                 1 Vancouver - general area   Jan 2000
           Mew Gull                 1                Vancouver   Jan 2000
      American Coot                 4             Maplewood 00   Jan 2000
      American Coot                 2             Maplewood 00   Jan 2000
      American Coot                 1    Iona Island (general)   Jan 2000
```

I am trying to create another column in the data frame called "Season" which groups the months of Jan, Feb, Mar and calls them Winter and groups the months Oct, Nov, Dec into Fall. This is the code I wrote to do this:

```
metrobirds$Season<-ifelse(metrobirds$Month==c("Jan","Feb","Mar"),"Winter","Fall")
```

However, when I view the dataframe, R has not correctly grouped the data in the new column. For example, many of the rows with Jan, Feb, or Mar are indicated as Fall and some are correctly indicated as Winter. What's wrong with my code? Any suggestions to correct this error?

When I read the csv file into R, I converted columns that were identified as factors into characters (e.g. common name, month, and locality), so those columns should be being read as characters.

Thanks for your help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `%in%`,

```
metrobirds$Season<-ifelse(metrobirds$Month %in% c("Jan","Feb","Mar"),"Winter","Fall")
```

Comment: @KateFremlin You can accept the answer by clicking on the check box below the vote if this works for you.